# How to report findings to show lack of correlation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am looking at the relationship between two variables. Contrary to custom my given h0 is "there is a significant correlation" and my h1 is "there is no significant correlation".

I calculated a bravais-pearson-coefficient of r(8) = .09, p = .806 which obviously would not indicate a significant correlation. How should I report the finding in respect of my h0 and h1?

I am aware that I cannot fully prove the absence of correlation but I was thinking about calculating the statistical power as a way to derive and report the propability of a type II-error. Is that a reasonable approach? 
Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: No. Look for "test of equivalence" or "two one-sided tests ([tag:tost])". In short, define what correlation is small enough for you (let's say 0.2) and then test r>0.2 and r<-0.2. Alternatively (and equivalently), compute confidence interval around your .09 estimate. Values outside of your confidence interval you can reject.

Comment: What is r(8) = .09 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show weak or absent (linear) correlation is as straight forward as reporting significant correlation.

As an example, I'll use the `USArrests` data set in R.

Say my null hypothesis before seeing the data is $H_{0}: \rho > 0$ between *Murder* and *Urban Population* at a 95% confidence level.

We can calculate the Pearson correlation statistic $(r)$ for our data, and an associate *t*-statistic.

$$
\displaystyle t = \frac{r \sqrt{n - 2}}{\sqrt{1 - r^2}}
$$

For this data set, $n = 50$, $r = 0.06957262$ and $t = 0.4831841$ with $df = n-2 = 48$ and $p$-value of $0.6844191$. The null hypothesis has $t_{df=48}(0.95) = 1.677$, and it is easy to see that the p-value > 0.05, so we fail to reject the null hypothesis that there is significant correlation.

Or simply, in R

```
> cor.test(x = USArrests$Murder, y = USArrests$UrbanPop, conf.level=0.95, alternative="greater", method = "pearson")

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  USArrests$Murder and USArrests$UrbanPop
t = 0.48318, df = 48, p-value = 0.3156
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.1686156  1.0000000
sample estimates:
    cor 
0.06957262
```

[image: Linear Relationship between Murder and Urban Pop]

Another thing to consider is doing simple linear regression. Linear regression can be used to indicate if there is a strong linear relationship (i.e. correlation) between two variables.

In R, this is easy to do.

```
> fit = lm(formula=Murder ~ UrbanPop, data = USArrests)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Murder ~ UrbanPop, data = USArrests)

Residuals:
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-6.537 -3.736 -0.779  3.332  9.728 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  6.41594    2.90669   2.207   0.0321 *
UrbanPop     0.02093    0.04333   0.483   0.6312  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.39 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.00484,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01589 
F-statistic: 0.2335 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 0.6312
```

The summary output show that the $\beta_{UrbanPop} = 0.02093$ which is very close to zero.

```
> anova(fit)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Murder
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
UrbanPop   1   4.50  4.4994  0.2335 0.6312
Residuals 48 925.05 19.2719               
>
```

The ANOVA table show that the F-statistic is also very small, with a large p-value of 0.6312. A hypothesis test for $H_0: \beta \neq 0$ would fail to reject the null hypothesis. More important than reporting a low p-value is reporting significant effect sizes, and here we are lacking any strength in our linear regression parameters.

Another thing to point out is that if you take the square-root of the Multipe R-squared you will get

```
> sqrt(0.00484)
[1] 0.06957011
```

which is the Pearson correlation statistic.

So to summarize, reporting lack of strength of correlation is not too dissimilar from reporting strength of correlation between two variables. This can be done through

1. a t-test
2. linear regression

However, what should be highlighted are visualizations and *effect sizes*, $r = 0.06957262$ and $\beta = 0.02093$ and the $R^2 = 0.00484$.

For a reference, please see: [Hypothesis Test for the Population Correlation Coefficient](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/259) and [Minitab's guide](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/regression/how-to/correlation/interpret-the-results/) and [Bravais-Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients: meaning, test of hypothesis and confidence interval](http://qpcrupdate.eu/artusi-corr-2002.pdf).

Hope this helps!